# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method - Include + Where

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this working Code

```
var h = db.MyTable.Include("Children").Include("Parent").ToList();
```

but when I add where condition

```
var h = db.MyTable.Include("Children").Include("Parent").Where(x => x.Country==Session["country"].ToString()).ToList();
```

it throws me an error

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_item (System.String)' method , and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can i rewrite it ? Im beginner :-)
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by your `Where`-Expression. You should only use variables in there or call methods that can be translated to SQL.

First, save your Session value in a variable:

```
var country = Session["country"].ToString();
```

Then use `country` in your `Where`-Expression.

[MSDN provides a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) of methods you can use inside LINQ to SQL expressions and how they are mapped to SQL functions.

Comment: What if you have something like this: Session[x.Key] instead of given expression i.e what we have a dependency on the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var t = Session["country"].ToString();
var h = db.MyTable.Include("Children").Include("Parent").Where(x => x.Country==t).ToList();
```

only activities can be parsed into expression-tree that is supported by your provider